# Is there any atomicMul() in cuda?

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, atomic

I have a cuda code where each thread in the device perform some operations and in the end each thread has to multiplicate its own result to the value of a variable in the global memory.
I'm looking for a function to do that final multiplication in an atomic way to avoid critical races but actually a found out only atomicAdd, sub, ecc ecc... Does it exists ? The values are double type.

Comment: You can cheat in some cases with log/exp functions and atomicAdd since `a * b` = `exp(log(a) + log(b))`.

Comment: You could also do it in two steps. First collect a list of results and then multiply either with one dedicated thread or with a reduction technique.